# PHP doesn't work with my Apache

Tags: apache-http-server, php

While starting the *httpd* service this error happens:

```
archlinux httpd[20575]: httpd: 
Syntax error on line 543 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: 
Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/httpd/conf/mods-enabled/php.conf:
Can't locate API module structure 'php5_module' in file /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so:
/etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so: undefined symbol: php5_module
```

I don't know how to solve this, I wish someone could help me with this!

There's my list of modules in `/etc/httpd/modules`:

[Output: ls /etc/httpd/modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3Q1n.png)

php.conf configuration:

```
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so

Include conf/extra/php5_module.conf
```

Comment: Sorry if I doesn't give more information about this error, but, if someone needs to see X configuration file I could show it.

Comment: Hopefully you aren't really trying to use version 5 of PHP. Find out what version of PHP you actually have which will determine the name of the interface module you will need to use in the Apache configuration file.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the help! You're right, my PHP version is 8.2.1, where I need to replace?

Comment: I'm new in PHP or Apache, sorry for not having the necessary experience.

Comment: Not sure what the name is on Linux but on Windows the interface module is named `php8apache2_4`. Look in the PHP directory and you should be able to find the name there.

Comment: In the /etc/httpd/modules directory there's a lot of modules.

There's one called libphp.so

Comment: It will have Apache in the name.

Comment: I put a few outputs and the configuration of php.ini in the answer so I can make things a bit easier.

Comment: The module in question is in the PHP directory not the Apache directory. It is named in the Apache configuration file. Those lines in `php.ini` that reference PHP 5 probably do not need to be there.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, that lines are from php.conf. If I delete the last 2 lines It works, but doing a phpinfo(); for testing when I use localhost/info.php it only shows the code, not the PHP information.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're trying to use prefork + mod_php at all? Generally php-fpm is the recommended and more reliable option, and this kind of problem wouldn't even exist with fpm (as well as not limiting you to mpm_prefork).

Comment: @Dave PHP 5 is still the standard version supported on REL 7 and it’s derivatives. The web developers on my systems have insisted on upgrades but you’ll have to take it up with Red Hat if you have a problem with it being installed.

Comment: Wow, that's not a good thing. PHP 5 is not something to be used in production at this point that's for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is solved.

This is my configuration for `/etc/httpd/conf/mods-enabled/php.conf`

```
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
LoadModule php_module "/etc/httpd/modules/libphp.so"
Include conf/extra/php_module.conf
```

Added this lines in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Below Loads

```
LoadModule php_module modules/libphp.so
AddHandler php-script .php
```

At the end of the file

```
IncludeOptional conf/sites-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional conf/mods-enabled/*.conf

Include conf/extra/php_module.conf
LoadModule php_module "/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp8.0.so"
```

I hope this helps other people as well this users and Arch Forum did, thanks!

Comment: There's the option that @user1686 commented in the answer of using php-fpm.